# no suitable method found for add(String) method Collection.add(Hostel) is not applicable (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to Hostel)

Tags: android, json, string, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I have an error for no suitable method found for add(String) method Collection.add(Hostel) is not applicable (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to Hostel).how to convert in a string to the hostel... I have sent it my full code.and then string value is converted to the Hostel object

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest( Request.Method.GET, url,null,
           new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                   try {
                       JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("response");
                       JSONArray jsonArray =data.getJSONArray( "products" );
                       for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                       {
                           JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject( i );
                           jsonLatitude = jsonObject.getString("latitude");
                           jsonLongitude = jsonObject.getString("longitude");
                           double distance=distance( Double.parseDouble( jsonLatitude ),Double.parseDouble(jsonLongitude ),GeoLat,GeoLong);
                            if(!(3 <= distance)){
                                jsonName = jsonObject.getString("pname");


                                //price means phone number 1
                                jsonMobile1 = jsonObject.getString("price");


                                //discount means phone number 2
                                jsonMobile2=jsonObject.getString( "discount" );
                                // address means pdescription details
                                jsonAddress=jsonObject.getString("pdescription");
                                //area means city name
                                jsonArea=jsonObject.getString( "area" );

                                JSONArray jsonImage = jsonObject.getJSONArray("image");
                                jsonPhoto = jsonImage.getString(0);

                               hostelList.add( jsonName );
                               hostelList.add(jsonMobile1);

                            }

                       }


                       shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmerAnimation();
                       shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility( View.GONE);


                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }

               },new Response.ErrorListener() {


       @Override
       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

   });

   AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest, tag_json_obj);
```

Comment: private List<Hostel> hostelList=new ArrayList<>(  );

Comment: ArrayList<String>hostelList=new ArrayList<>();

Comment: the error occurred

Comment: what kind of error??

Comment: Error the only hotelList.add(jsonName);

Comment: can you post your whole code

Comment: You didn't show what is a `jsonName`

Comment: json name,jsonmobile1,jsonMobile2,... string only.if convert to add
(com.example.sankar.nestfindersapp.Hostel)
in List cannot be applied
to
(java.lang.String)

Comment: Json Name is String

Comment: can you past whole code because its difficult to understand in this piece of code

Answer (score 0):

Actually for this problem you have to create a custom model class which contains strings and other variable. Which is according to need of data you want from the json.
And then `ArrayList<ModelClass> nameArrray=new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: string value to add the recycler view Hostel.java class.....so the error would be occured

Comment: but these variable are String jsonMobile1, jsonMobile2, jsonAddress, jsonArea, jsonPhoto